# Unicode syntax error using graph.sound_bake in Blender

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a audio visualizer in Blender, using Python, and my code keeps throwing this syntax error.

```
SyntaxError:(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape location: unknown location :-1
```

```py
# python file
bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath="C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Teardrop.mp3", low= i*step, high=i*step+step)
```

Comment: In the future please include the full traceback of any errors you receive. It's critical for us to help troubleshoot. And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

On this line:

```
bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=r"C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Teardrop.mp3", low= i*step, high=i*step+step)
```

the `\U` in the filepath string is being interpreted as an escape sequence:

```
>>> '\U'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>>
```

---

To fix the problem, place an `r` before the string:

```
bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=r"C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Teardrop.mp3", low= i*step, high=i*step+step)
```

This will convert it into a [raw-string](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), which do not process escape sequences:

```
>>> r'\U'
'\\U'
>>>
```

---

An alternate solution would be to turn the backslashes into forwardslashes:

```
bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath="C:/Users/Callum/Desktop/Teardrop.mp3", low= i*step, high=i*step+step)
```

Even though you are running Windows, Python works just fine with forwardslashes in filepaths.

Comment: this works too, I just changed all the "\" to "/" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things:

```
if c == columns:
r += 1
c = 0
```

should be

```
if c == columns:
    r += 1
    c = 0
```

and

```
bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath="C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Teardrop.mp3", low= i*step, high=i*step+step
```

is missing the closing parenthesis.